# How to group data in laravel?

Tags: laravel

In a Laravel application I would like to prepare the data for a graph as follows:

```
{ 
"Dächer": 
    [ 
       { "main_product_group_id": 4, "main_product_group_name": "Dächer", "net_amount": 421.85 }, 
       { "main_product_group_id": 4, "main_product_group_name": "Dächer", "net_amount": 100 }
    ],
"Türen und Eingänge":
    [
      { "main_product_group_id": 2, "main_product_group_name": "Türen und Eingänge", "net_amount": 4687.9 }
    ]
}
```

Controller:

```
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $orders = Order::all();

        $data = CockpitOrderDataResource::collection($orders);

        $dataGroupByMainProduct = $data->groupBy('main_product_group_name');

        return response()->json($dataGroupByMainProduct->all());
    }
```

I get the following result:

```
{ 
"": 
    [ 
       { "main_product_group_id": 4, "main_product_group_name": "Dächer", "net_amount": 421.85 }, 
       { "main_product_group_id": 4, "main_product_group_name": "Dächer", "net_amount": 100 },
       { "main_product_group_id": 2, "main_product_group_name": "Türen und Eingänge", "net_amount": 4687.9 }
    ]
}
```

If I change the groupBy function to `$data->groupBy('main_product_group_id')`, i get the following result (which is correct):

```
{ 
"4": 
    [ 
       { "main_product_group_id": 4, "main_product_group_name": "Dächer", "net_amount": 421.85 }, 
       { "main_product_group_id": 4, "main_product_group_name": "Dächer", "net_amount": 100 }
    ],
"2":
    [
      { "main_product_group_id": 2, "main_product_group_name": "Türen und Eingänge", "net_amount": 4687.9 }
    ]
}
```

Why doesn't work this `$data->groupBy('main_product_group_name')` and the group name is empty?

Comment: It looks fine to me, I can only think that groupBy method is not able to to support special chars like the 'ä' to create the array index using groupBy. Can you try with just 'Dacher' ? To discard this theory. Thanks